# Updating timestamps in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How do I update/change the TimestampSequence on a Mongoid document in rails/ruby?
If you dont know in Mongoid but know in MongoDB that will work as well.

The class is Mongoid::TimestampSequence

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Document.where(somecriteriahere: "criteriavaluehere").update_all(
  updated_at: Time.now.to_s)
```